# The value of variant does not show in run time in debug mode

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-debugging

When I want in debug mode get the value of variant, I cannot get it.
On the other hand the value of the variant does not show in run time in debug mode!

I use `Visual Studio 2015`.

How can I solve this problem?
[image]

Comment: @ Jahan, like this sample here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.appsettings(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2, just using the same App.config file with a simple code like  var appSettings1 = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Setting1"]; Could you get the value for appSettings1 during debugging time? If it works well in your side, I think you would think about your project itself like  the "domain" value. Do you get any error or warning if you put the mouse on the var after the breakpoint was hit in next line code?

Comment: There is no problem about existing the value. But I cannot see the value of variants in debug mode. domainName is for example.

Comment: @ Jahan, whether a breakpoint was hit in the next code line of this variant line? How about using a simple new App.config file like the sample in my previous comment? Of course, you could take a back up for your previous config file . Since I couldn't repro this issue in my VS2015, if possible, share me a simple sample would be better.

Comment: Previously I could see the value of variants but now I cannot see it. Perhaps there is a mistake in VS2015. Maybe I should reset the settings but how?!

Comment: To reset the VS settings, TOOLS->Import and Export Settings Wizard->Reset all settings->select “No, just reset settings, overwriting my current settings”->Choose a Default Collection of settings. Or you could create a new blank solution, and then add all project files to the new blank solution. Clean and rebuild it, check the result.

Comment: @ Jahan, any update? Would you please share us the latest information about this issue?

Comment: I uninstalled VS and reinstalled again. Now everything is good. I couldn't find another way, unfortunately.

Comment: If so, maybe it really is the VS setup issue. Glad to know it works well now. Would you please post it as the answer? Jahan:) Have a nice day.

Comment: Thank you, Jack :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I uninstalled Visual Studio and reinstalled again. Now everything is good. I couldn't find another way, unfortunately.